# Qafih edition of Bustan al-Uqul Online?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet

Is  R. Yosef Qafih's translation [גן השכלים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D)  by R. Nathanel al-Fayumi available online somewhere? It seems to appear [here](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?149871) in Otzar HaChochma but only the first 40 pages.

Comment: snippet view: https://books.google.ca/books?id=5q3XAAAAMAAJ&q="גן+השכלים"&dq="גן+השכלים"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi89u-99e_eAhVl4oMKHWuTB5AQ6AEIKDAA

Comment: The whole sefer is available on Otzar if you purchase a subscription. But I'm assuming you're looking for it online for free.

Comment: Here is an English translation https://books.google.com/books?id=BpNAAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2):

[The newer edition](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=149871&pagenum=1), also by Rabbi Qafich, is available for free in the site of the Genizah Project, [here](https://ja.genizah.org/GeneralPages/ViewResources.aspx?titleId=80#) (the link takes you automatically to the Judeo-Arabic text. Just press on צילום מקור to go to the Qafich edition). You may need to sign up (for free), first.

And, adding for general reference, the 1908 English translation by David Levine mentioned by @wfb in the comments can be accessed for free [here](https://archive.org/details/bustanalukul00levigoog).

Comment: Note the link I posed to Otzar Hachochmah has it as completely free right now and can be viewed there, but probably after the current Israeli shutdown ends, it won't be free anymore.